# Engine stalls only in hot whether when starting

Tags: stall, idle, jetta, hot-start

I have a VOLKSWAGEN JETTA 2015 (Petrol) with 100,000KM approximately. It normally drives perfectly alright except when it's hot outside. If the whether is hot outside, the car stalls when starting, so I have to give li'l pedal to keep it going. Once I push it above 3,000 RPM it stabilizes, and after that no problem whatsoever.

One thing though, it does have any issue when the engine is really hot after long distance drving,it's just when the outside temperature is hot. wth!

The mechanic checked for diagnostics but he did not find any issue with is OBD2 readings. He said "*its not throttle body issue, otherwise engine might run rough"*. he continued, "*usually it might be fuel injector issue, try using Fuel injector cleaner for twice and see what happens.*"

I also checked if my car has the Mass Airflow Sensor issue but it turned out, JETTA 2015 does not have MAF sensor.

I still have 3000KM to replace the oil, kept 100% full in coolant. I am not sure it's got anything to do with battery! I can't think of anything else!?

Has anyone seen similar problems or have any advice for how to proceed?

**PS: Petrol car, SE Edition. 2.0L (No TSI nor TDI)**

Comment: Tell us which engine it has and which fuel it takes.

Comment: @HandyHowie updated the answer. Its petrol engine.

Comment: Where did you get told it doesn't have a MAF? I'm pretty sure it does.

Comment: it usually sits near Airfilter compartment but I didn't find any for this model

Comment: Tell us the engine size.

Comment: 2.0L @HandyHowie

Answer (score 1):

With VWs, this problem [is usually the fuel pump](https://www.vwvortex.com/threads/stalling-when-hot.5729752/).  Replicate the problem while your mechanic checks the fuel pressure.  If it is abnormally low, replace the fuel pump.